# How to resolve Telegram API error . 403 CHAT_WRITE_FORBIDDEN You can't write in this chat

Tags: javascript, telegram

Basically I have a group(of which I am admin) in which I want to be able to add and kick-out user programmatically. I created a telegram app  using my telegram account. I wanted to  access the method `channels.EditBanned`. The group was created using same account that was used to create app.  This one:

```
new Api.channels.EditBanned({
  channel: "Test_Channel",
  participant: "vishalkale151071",
  bannedRights: new Api.ChatBannedRights({
    untilDate: 43,
    viewMessages: 0,
    sendMessages: 1,
    sendMedia: true,
    sendStickers: true,
    sendGifs: false,
    sendGames: true,
    sendInline: true,
    sendPolls: true,
    changeInfo: true,
    inviteUsers: true,
    pinMessages: true,
  }),
})
);
```

But got error :

> RPCError: 403: CHAT_WRITE_FORBIDDEN (caused by channels.EditBanned)

Reference : https://gram.js.org/tl/channels/EditBanned

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram/issues/1518) could be related to administrators not having writing permissions. Did you checked that?

Comment: Ok . I will look into it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to ban/kick someone you can use:

```
new Api.channels.EditBanned({
      channel: new Api.InputChannel({
        channelId: <channel_id>,
        accessHash: BigInt(<hash>),
      }),
      participant: <user_id>,
      bannedRights: new Api.ChatBannedRights({
        untilDate: 43,
        viewMessages: true,
        sendMessages: true,
        sendMedia: true,
        sendStickers: true,
        sendGifs: true,
        sendGames: true,
        sendInline: true,
        sendPolls: true,
        changeInfo: true,
        inviteUsers: true,
        pinMessages: true,
      }),
    })
```

to get the channel accessHash and id, you must store the result when you call the createChannel:

```
const result = await client.invoke(
    new Api.channels.CreateChannel({
      title: "grupo-legal-2",
      about: "about test",
      broadcast: true,
      // megagroup: true,
      // forImport: true,
      geoPoint: new Api.InputGeoPoint({
        lat: -26.30444,
        long: -48.84556,
        accuracyRadius: 100,
      }),
      address: "address test",
    })
  );

  console.log(result);
  console.log(result.chats[0].id);
  console.log(result.chats[0].accessHash);
```

Comment: How do you get the access hash for channel .

Comment: Ok  . Since I had a deadline for the project , I ended up achieving the delete functionality by creating a bot and invoking bot.banMember method . For this to work one need to add the bot to the telegram group with admin privileges . also I feel its much simpler this way . Apart from directly messaging users in telegram , you can pretty much do everything .

Comment: @SiddharthBhoite when you use `Api.channels.CreateChannel` the response 
 access_hash came with  `chats` array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok . Since I had a deadline for the project , I ended up achieving the delete functionality by creating a bot and invoking bot.banMember method . For this to work one need to add the bot to the telegram group with admin privileges . also I feel its much simpler this way . Apart from directly messaging users in telegram , you can pretty much do everything . –